# Postgres Continuous Archiving and Point-in-Time Recovery (PITR)

Tags: postgresql, database-backups

I am trying to setup Continuous Archiving and Point-in-Time Recovery (PITR) in Postgres. When I go through the [documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/continuous-archiving.) it says:

> The archive command should generally be designed to refuse to overwrite any pre-existing archive file. This is an important safety feature to preserve the integrity of your archive in case of administrator error (such as sending the output of two different servers to the same archive directory).

But I see that the same WAL file is changing multiple times when I open a connection and do some changes time to time. So for example, when I first connect the database and do some changes (like deleting or inserting some rows), it creates a WAL file named **000000010000000000000090** and my archive_command is immediately run. My archive_command is

```
test ! -f /mnt/server/archivedir/%f && cp %p /mnt/server/archivedir/%f
```

This is based on the documentation, which checks if the file already exists in the archive directory, if exists, it doesn't copy and copies only if the file doesn't exist. So the first time the condition passes and the file is copied, but when I am doing some more changes with the same connection (I am even having the same issue when I reconnect from the same PC) the original WAL file is being changed. But the next time the copy doesn't work because the file already exists.

If this is allowed to happen, we may lose some changes in the backup. Anyone knows about any solution, so it creates a new file for every change instead of modifying the old file?

> I am using Postgres version 10.2 on my local computer (Mac).

Answer (score 0):

Does that really happen to you? Because it shouldn't.

PostgreSQL writes transaction logs in “WAL files” (WAL for *Write Ahead Log*) of 16MB size.

Whenever a WAL file is full, the log is switched to a new WAL file, and the old WAL file is archived with `archive_command`.

If `archive_command` completes with an exit status of 0 (success), the WAL file is recycled, otherwise archiving is retried until it succeeds. Failures will be logged.

Anyway, as long as there are no errors, **each WAL file will only be archived once**.

The behavior you describe shouldn't happen.

Check the PostgreSQL log to see if there were errors reported form `archive_command`. If you fix the error condition. normal operation will be resumed.

Comment: Thanks. I just checked the postgres.log file (located in /usr/local/var/log/ folder) and didn't see any error logged there. 
By the way, I see another issue now. I see the WAL file name is changing by each connection created, though the contents are incrementing as you said. (Currently the file name is 000000010000000000000093 after being changed as ..91 and ..92). I can see the ..90, ..91 and ..92 files copied to the archive directory, but not the ..93 version. To be noted again, all files contents are same (incrementing).

Comment: How do you determine the file content? What is "incrementing" in that context?

Comment: I only determine by the file size.

Comment: The files are different. All WAL files are preallocated with 16MB. The numbering determines the order of WAL files. Each WAL file is only archived once (unless there is an error, which is logged).